# Tricks to speed up solution of a pair of nonlinear symbolic equations

Tags: python, sympy

I have two equations f1(b,bb) = 0 and f2(b,bb) = 0 defined in the following code. I am trying to find the set of (b,bb) that satisfy both.

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import symbols, simplify, factor

a, b, aa, bb, q, l, h = symbols('a b aa bb q l h')

pb = l*q+h*(1-q)
pb0 = (l*(1-l)*q+h*(1-h)*(1-q))/((1-l)*q+(1-h)*(1-q))
pb1 = (l**2*q+h**2*(1-q))/(l*q+h*(1-q))
a = b*bb/(2*b*bb*l**2 - 3*b*bb*l + b*bb - 2*b*l**2 + 2*b*l - 2*bb*l**2 + 2*bb*l + 2*l**2 - 2)
aa = 2/(l*(2*b*bb*l - b*bb - 2*b*l - 2*bb*l + 2*l + 2))

f1 = 1/pb*((1+(1-aa)/(2*aa*pb1))*q*l*b - (1-(1-aa)/(2*aa*pb1))*(1-q)*h*bb) - 1
f2 = 1/(1-pb)*(1+(1-a)/(2*a*pb0))*(q*(1-l)*b+(1-q)*(1-h)*bb) - 1

sp.solvers.solve((f1,f2), (b,bb))
```

The solver is taking a prohibitively long time (no solution yet).

I believe the above system is bilinear.

Are there any tricks to speed things up, i.e., python packages that exploit the bilinear structure? Maybe an alternate solver that is more efficient? I am hoping that I don't have to resort to a numerical solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you solve f1 for b and substitute it into f2 you end up with an expression that has a numerator that is cubic in bb and does not factor. Solving a symbolic cubic is not going to be fast. About the best you can do is identify the coefficients and substitute them into the general solutions of the cubic equation.

```
>>> gen = Tuple(*solve(A*x**3+B*x**2+C*x+D,x))
>>> bbexpr = f2.subs(b, solve(f1, b)[0])
>>> n = bbexpr.as_numer_denom()[0].expand()
```

Then for each coefficient, something like this (for the first coeff):

```
>>> eA = n.coeff(bb**3)
>>> gen = gen.subs(A, eA)
```

Spoiler alert: it's going to be unwieldy.